# How to write a REST API for nodejs to return a random number?

Tags: node.js, api

In fallowing code which is generating a 5 digits number and I would like to make a single API to call this code and return a random number. something like:

> https://sub.mydomain.com/getnumber

```
function getnumber() {
    var code = "";
    var possible = "1234567890";

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      code += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      if (i == 0 && code == "0") {
        code = "7"
      }
    }
    return code;
  }
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Do some research, and then come back to ask if you face any problem.

Comment: I don't want to use 3rd parties like expressjs which most of  guides uses them.

Comment: Google `node.js http server`

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert at all but as you get on comments  `node.js http server` is your solution:

try this little one code:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  if (request.method === 'GET' && request.url === '/getnumber') {
    request.pipe(response);
    response.end(getnumber());
  } else {
    response.statusCode = 404;
    response.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);

function getnumber() {
    var code = "";
    var possible = "1234567890";

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      code += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      if (i == 0 && code == "0") {
        code = "7"
      }
    }
    return code;
  }
```

your URL should be like:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/getnumber
```